# Altering query to filer on a field but not getting the result I need

Tags: sql

I have an already written script that I am trying to modify by using one more field to filter by. It seems like I can't get it to look at the field even though there are no errors.
The query looks for deposits that were incorrect and a deposit correction notice needs to be sent, we are now doing some of that by email. So I am trying to filter out those who receive it by email.

The query is already using the table that has the field I want to use but it is not doing the job.

The filter is:

`where addres.pax <> '1'`

When I select against the addres table with this I get back everything where that field does not equal 1, and I can do `where addres.pax = '1'` and I get everything back that has a 1 in that field.

But in the larger query, the field is not populated.

I am in our test system. I have the data dictionary, I can get the results I want from a simple query.

```
use TEST
Declare @CashCentreId as VARCHAR (30)
set @CashCentreId = '0000000A000000660000000008A5C'
SELECT
  CASHCENTRE.LINK AS CASHCENTREID
, CASHCENTRE.CODE AS CASHCENTRECODE
, COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK AS AGGID
, CONVERT(date, COUNTINGAGGREGATION.CREATION) AS CREATIONDATE
, ('XXXX-XX' + RIGHT(ISNULL(BANK1.ACCOUNTNUMBER,ISNULL(BANK2.ACCOUNTNUMBER,'    ')),4)) AS Account
, CLIENT.NAME AS AccountName
, ISNULL(ADRESS.STREET,'') AS ClientStreet
, ISNULL((ADRESS.CITY + ', ' + ADRESS.STATE + ' ' + ADRESS.CODE),'') AS ClientCityStatePostal
, CCADRESS.PHONE AS PhoneNumber
, CCADRESS.EMAIL as Email
, CCADRESS.PAX as DepCorEmail
, CLIENT.NAME AS Location
, CASE WHEN COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED IS NULL OR COUNTINGCONFIG.RULETYPE = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(DECLARED) FROM maestro.COUNTING WHERE COUNTING.LAGGREGATE = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK)
    ELSE COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED
  END AS DepositAmount
, COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMNOTETRUE+COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMCOINTRUE+COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMOTHERTRUE AS CorrectAmount
, (ISNULL(COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMNOTETRUE,0)+ISNULL(COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMCOINTRUE,0)+ISNULL(COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMOTHERTRUE,0)) -
  (CASE WHEN COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED IS NULL OR COUNTINGCONFIG.RULETYPE = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(DECLARED) FROM maestro.COUNTING WHERE COUNTING.LAGGREGATE = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK)
    ELSE COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED
   END) AS AdjustmentAmount
, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 REASONDEF.NAME
          FROM maestro.REASONS REASONS
          INNER JOIN maestro.REASONDEF REASONDEF ON REASONS.LREASONDEF = REASONDEF.LINK
          WHERE REASONS.LCOUNTINGAGG = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK
          ORDER BY REASONS.CREATION ASC),
          (SELECT TOP 1 REASONDEF.NAME
          FROM maestro.REASONS REASONS
          INNER JOIN maestro.REASONDEF REASONDEF ON REASONS.LREASONDEF = REASONDEF.LINK
          WHERE REASONS.LCOUNTING in (SELECT LINK FROM maestro.COUNTING WHERE COUNTING.LAGGREGATE = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK)
          ORDER BY REASONS.CREATION ASC)) As AdjustmentReason
FROM
maestro.COUNTINGAGGREGATION COUNTINGAGGREGATION
INNER JOIN maestro.COUNTING COUNTING ON (COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK = COUNTING.LAGGREGATE AND COUNTINGAGGREGATION.NAME = COUNTING.NAME)
INNER JOIN maestro.COUNTINGCONFIG COUNTINGCONFIG ON COUNTING.LRULE = COUNTINGCONFIG.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.CLIENT CLIENT ON COUNTING.LCLIENT = CLIENT.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS ADRESS ON CLIENT.ADR = ADRESS.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.CASHCENTRE CASHCENTRE ON COUNTING.LCASHCENTRE = CASHCENTRE.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS CCADRESS ON CASHCENTRE.LADDRESS = CCADRESS.LINK
LEFT OUTER JOIN maestro.BANKING BANK1 on CLIENT.BANKING1 = BANK1.LINK
LEFT OUTER JOIN maestro.BANKING BANK2 on CLIENT.BANKING2 = BANK2.LINK
WHERE COUNTINGAGGREGATION.COMPLETED = 1
AND (COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME NOT LIKE '%Master Bag%' OR (COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME LIKE '%Master Bag%' AND COUNTINGCONFIG.MASTERBAGRULE = 1))
AND CASHCENTRE.LINK = @CashCentreId
AND CHARINDEX('Blind', COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME) = 0
AND 
((CASHCENTRE.CODE = 194 AND 
  (CASE WHEN COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED IS NULL OR COUNTINGCONFIG.RULETYPE = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(DECLARED) FROM maestro.COUNTING WHERE COUNTING.LAGGREGATE = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK)
    ELSE COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED
   END - COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMNOTETRUE-COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMCOINTRUE-COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMOTHERTRUE) <> 0)
  OR
 (CASHCENTRE.CODE <> 194 AND 
   ABS(CASE WHEN COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED IS NULL OR COUNTINGCONFIG.RULETYPE = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(DECLARED) FROM maestro.COUNTING WHERE COUNTING.LAGGREGATE = COUNTINGAGGREGATION.LINK)
        ELSE COUNTINGAGGREGATION.DECLARED
       END - COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMNOTETRUE-COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMCOINTRUE-COUNTINGAGGREGATION.SUMOTHERTRUE) > 1))
UNION ALL

SELECT
  CASHCENTRE.LINK AS CASHCENTREID
, CASHCENTRE.CODE AS CASHCENTRECODE
, COUNTING.LINK AS AGGID
, CONVERT(date, COUNTING.CREATION) AS CREATIONDATE
, ('XXXX-XX' + RIGHT(ISNULL(BANK1.ACCOUNTNUMBER,ISNULL(BANK2.ACCOUNTNUMBER,'    ')),4)) AS Account
, CLIENT.NAME AS AccountName
, ISNULL(ADRESS.STREET,'') AS ClientStreet
, ISNULL((ADRESS.CITY + ', ' + ADRESS.STATE + ' ' + ADRESS.CODE),'') AS ClientCityStatePostal
, CCADRESS.PHONE AS PhoneNumber
, CCADRESS.EMAIL as Email
, CLIENT.NAME AS Location
, CCADRESS.PAX as DepCorEmail
, COUNTING.DECLARED AS DepositAmount
, COUNTING.SUMNOTETRUE+COUNTING.SUMCOINTRUE+COUNTING.SUMOTHERTRUE AS CorrectAmount
, (COUNTING.SUMNOTETRUE+COUNTING.SUMCOINTRUE+COUNTING.SUMOTHERTRUE) - COUNTING.DECLARED AS AdjustmentAmount
, (SELECT TOP 1 REASONDEF.NAME
          FROM maestro.REASONS REASONS
          INNER JOIN maestro.REASONDEF REASONDEF ON REASONS.LREASONDEF = REASONDEF.LINK
          WHERE REASONS.LCOUNTING = COUNTING.LINK
          ORDER BY REASONS.CREATION ASC) As AdjustmentReason
FROM
maestro.COUNTING COUNTING
INNER JOIN maestro.COUNTINGCONFIG COUNTINGCONFIG ON COUNTING.LRULE = COUNTINGCONFIG.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.CLIENT CLIENT ON COUNTING.LCLIENT = CLIENT.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS ADRESS ON CLIENT.ADR = ADRESS.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.CASHCENTRE CASHCENTRE ON COUNTING.LCASHCENTRE = CASHCENTRE.LINK
INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS CCADRESS ON CASHCENTRE.LADDRESS = CCADRESS.LINK
LEFT OUTER JOIN maestro.BANKING BANK1 on CLIENT.BANKING1 = BANK1.LINK
LEFT OUTER JOIN maestro.BANKING BANK2 on CLIENT.BANKING2 = BANK2.LINK
WHERE COUNTING.COMPLETED = 1
AND (COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME LIKE '%Master Bag%' AND COUNTINGCONFIG.MASTERBAGRULE = 0)
AND CASHCENTRE.LINK = @CashCentreId
AND CHARINDEX('Blind', COUNTINGCONFIG.NAME) = 0
AND 
((CASHCENTRE.CODE = 194 AND 
  (COUNTING.DECLARED - COUNTING.SUMNOTETRUE-COUNTING.SUMCOINTRUE-COUNTING.SUMOTHERTRUE) <> 0)
  OR
 (CASHCENTRE.CODE <> 194 AND 
   ABS(COUNTING.DECLARED - COUNTING.SUMNOTETRUE-COUNTING.SUMCOINTRUE-COUNTING.SUMOTHERTRUE) > 1))
   and ADRESS.PAX = '1'
ORDER BY CASHCENTREID, AccountName, AGGID
```

Comment: The PAX field comes back empty even though I know that field is populated, and I have checked by running the where clause on the addres table and I get either everything with a one, or everything with the 1.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple to check, but you've aliased maestro.ADRESS as ADRESS and CCADRESS; have you tried seeing what you have in ADRESS.PAX in your select? Did you mean to give the same table two aliases?

Comment: I've tried making them all the same but I get errors in the joins then, I did not write this script, I am trying to alter it by adding one more field and using the where clause to filter. 
I've tried with ccaddres and with addres. But for sanity's sake I will try that again. 

I get results, but they don't seem to be coming from where I am asking. The addres.PAX field should have has a 1 in two of the rows, and  my email address in the email field, instead it had our general email address instead! Where is it getting that from? I cannot post results and they have client names.

Comment: I saw in your other answer that you figured it out, but be careful about using functions like ISNULL in join or where clauses as it could lead to significant performance issues if you have a whole lot of data. You may want to consider using: INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS ADRESS ON CLIENT.ADR = ADRESS.LINK with AND ADRESS.PAX <> '1' AND ADRESS.PAX IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

So! The answer is to edit both instances of this join
INNER JOIN maestro.ADRESS ADRESS ON CLIENT.ADR = ADRESS.LINK
with  AND ISNULL(ADRESS.PAX,'0') <> '1' and viola! It works!